# Same mapping for two different types using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's imagine I have classes UserInfoDto, UserDto and User

```
//Dto
public class UserInfoDto
{
     public string UserName {get; set;}
     public DateTime DoB {get; set;}
}

//Another Dto
public class UserDto
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
}

//DB model
public class User
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
}
```

And I want to create 2 mappings:

1. From UserInfoDto to UserDto
2. From UserInfoDto to User

   ```
    CreateMap<UserInfoDto, UserDto>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.UserName))
        .ForMember(d => d.DateOfBirth, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DoB))

    CreateMap<UserInfoDto, User>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.UserName))
        .ForMember(d => d.DateOfBirth, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DoB))
   ```

As you can see I have two identical mappings. Is there a way to create only one mapping (for example first one) and reuse the settings of this mapping for the second case?

I'm asking because in real-world code I have 20+ properties and I want to avoid duplication somehow.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it will work only if I have an inheritance (for example User -> UserDto), but I don't have one.

Comment: Yes. If you don't want that, you can use an interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your properties have same names, there is no need to explicitly map them. It is enough to do the following:

```
CreateMap<UserInfoDto, UserDto>();
CreateMap<UserInfoDto, User>();
```

So `Automapper` will map properties by their names by itself.

Comment: No, in my case properties are different, so I need to create a mapping for each type (like I show in my example), but the problem is these two mappings are the same. I'm considering this as a code duplication and I'm trying to find a way how to avoid it.